# Animated GIF breaking when changed

Tags: javascript

I've got what seems like a very simple problem but I'm having some problems fixing it. I'm trying to create an interactive cat object on my page with Javascript that basically performs the following expected behavior:

- When the page first loads, the cat is laying sleeping in the middle of the screen (cat-sleeping.gif)
- When you move the pointer (customized to look like a mouse) a little bit closer to the cat, it sits up and starts grooming itself (cat-sitting.gif)
- When you move the pointer even closer, the cat starts chasing after the cursor (cat-chasing.gif)

To handle detecting the mouse proximity and the chase behaviour, I'm using a loop that's being called from window.requestAnimationFrame after an initial setup call. The chase + mouse proximity are working as expected, but the changing animation states are not. Although the image changes as expected when the cat is activated, the animated gif becomes a static image. If it matters, I'm using Google Chrome to test things out.

Here's a snippet of the loop (note this function isn't completely finished, but everything that should be working so far works, except the animation)

```
function loop() {
  const { pointerEvent, pointerStatic, catActive } = state;
  const { cat, cursor } = settings;

  // Calculate distance between cat and pointer
  const distance = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(pointerEvent.x - cat.element.offsetLeft, 2) +
      Math.pow(pointerEvent.y - cat.element.offsetTop, 2)
  );

  // Normalize the distance
  const distanceNorm = scale(distance, 0, 1000);

  // Activate the cat after the pointer gets close enough
  if (distanceNorm < 0.1) {
    updateState({ catActive: true });
  }

  // Flip the cursor left or right depending on the direction of movement
  if (pointerEvent.movementX < 0) {
    cursor.element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
  } else {
    cursor.element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
  }

  // Make the cat turn from left to right when the pointer is moving
  if (pointerEvent.x < cat.element.offsetLeft + cat.width / 2) {
    cat.element.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
  } else {
    cat.element.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";
  }

  // If the cat is active, chase the pointer
  if (catActive) {
    cat.element.src = "cat-walk.gif";
    cat.element.style.left = `${toAbsolute(
      distanceNorm,
      cat.element.offsetLeft,
      pointerEvent.x - 80
    )}px`;
    cat.element.style.top = `${toAbsolute(
      distanceNorm,
      cat.element.offsetTop,
      pointerEvent.y - 35
    )}px`;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Comment: Just to rule things out, does this  `gif` file has the loop setup? Because, this `gif` could have the animation but it might be missing the loop instruction that makes it start again from the first frame.

Comment: Also, another thing to rule out, if you have a loop, could it be that it's reloading the `gif` in each iteration? Have you tried to load the `gif` outside the loop, then influence its behavior inside the loop?

Comment: The .gif is a looping animation, and has previously been working fine when interacted with inside the loop. It was the image I originally started out with when putting together the loop function, so it was working perfectly until I started trying to replace the images. Could it possibly be that the image is being loaded every frame by the loop, so it's forever stuck on the first frame?

Comment: Mmmh. I have my doubts about that. However, maybe this requires a different approach. How about having an array, where each element points to a different `gif`. Then, change the `cat` variable from being a constant to a regular variable, so you can reassign it with whatever element in that array works for you?

Comment: In other words, create an array, where each element is a loaded `gif`. You can thing of this as "pre-loading". Then, the variable `cat` make it a regular variable instead of a constant. Then, you can assign, from the array to the `cat` variable,  which `gif` you will be manipulating.

Comment: That just might work, I'll have to give it a shot and see!

Comment: Ok. Keep me informed please. I'm curious to see how it went.

Comment: That didn't seem to work (or perhaps I implemented it poorly, I'm kinda new to all this!) but I did.. half get it working? I tried separating my cat state from the pointer state since I realized that state's update function was getting called every time the pointer moves, and then created a separate updateCatState function that would change the cat's form depending on catActive or not, and this -almost- works. The cat walking .gif animates successfully, but only (and this seems a little bizarre) when I'm moving the pointer to the right side of the screen! It remains static otherwise.

Comment: I was able to get it to work (finally) by changing the updateCatState function. My restructuring of the 'catActive' boolean is for some reason not working, but if I access it directly, then suddenly it all just works. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my state function fixed this - I made a separate change state function specifically for the cat, since I realized that state was otherwise being updated every frame as the pointer moved due to sharing data with the PointerElement event. However, I'm not 100% sure why this actually worked - to make it function, I needed to directly access catActive from my catState object instead of using its destructured variant. I'm posting this as an answer so that I  can share the code, but I'd like to understand why this actually works so that I learn instead of surviving by trial and error!

```
function updateCatState(newState) {
  let { catActive, cat, catForm } = catState;
  catState = { ...catState, ...newState };

  if (catState.catActive && cat.element.src !== catForm[1]) {
    console.log("catActive");
    cat.element.src = catForm[1];
  } else {
    cat.element.src = catForm[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, lets go line by line. First, you create three variables from `catState`.

Comment: Then you replacing `catState` by merging of two objects, `catState` and `newState`. In the merge, matching properties' names will have their values replace by `newState`.

Comment: Next, If `catState.catActive` is false, you will assign `catForm[0]` to `cat.element.src`.

Comment: Or, if `catState.catActive` is true, you will alternate what `cat.element.src` is assigned to based on if `cat.element.src` doesn't match `catForm[1]`.

Comment: I understood this much, but I was mostly trying to figure out why I need to directly access catState.catActive - when I destructure this variable, it's not working.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing about `catState`. If you can include it into your question we might be able to find an answer.

Comment: I've unfortunately changed my code a bit too much since then and have implemented a different, more reliable system for changing the animations, so I'm going to accept my 'solution' for now and leave it here. This is for a project at Uni and I've been a bit bad about my version control, but I appreciate the help you gave me nonetheless!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you make it work and I wish you the best luck when you present it. Have a nice day :)